# Jacobi preconditioner versus unit-row or unit-column preconditioner

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms, condition-number

Given the system $Ax=b$, where $A$ is square and has only positive eigenvalues, one can solve the system using the preconditioned modified Richardson iteration: $x^{k+1} = (I-\omega M^{-1}A)x^k + \omega M^{-1}b$ with $\omega \in \left(0,\frac{2}{\rho(M^{-1}A)}\right)$, provided $M^{-1}A$ also has only positive eigenvalues. A popular choice is Jacobi preconditioning: $M^{-1} = (\operatorname{diag}(A))^{-1}$, which makes $M^{-1}A, AM^{-1}, M^{-\frac{1}{2}}AM^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ have unit diagonals. Is there any difference between the last three preconditioners? For example in terms of the condition number or the spectral radius? Are the spectral radii equal? Is there a proof that this preconditioning keeps the eigenvalues positive?

Now consider two alternative preconditioners $R^{-1}A$ or $AC^{-1}$ which normalize every row or column: $R_{ii} = \operatorname{diag}(\sum_j|A_{ij}|)$ or $C_{jj} = \operatorname{diag}(\sum_i|A_{ij}|)$. These preconditioners make it so that $\rho(R^{-1}A)\leq\|R^{-1}A\|_{\infty}=1$ and $\rho(AC^{-1})\leq\|AC^{-1}\|_1=1$. Are there any references comparing these to Jacobi and results on the condition number of the preconditioned matrix?

Edit: Thanks to Carl Chrisitian pointing out that the matrices are similar I  have:
$$M^{\frac{1}{2}}(M^{-1}A)M^{-\frac{1}{2}} = M^{-\frac{1}{2}}AM^{-\frac{1}{2}} = M^{-\frac{1}{2}}(AM^{-1})M^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

which means that the eigenvalues and thus spectral radii agree. This also means that $R^{-1}A$ and $AC^{-1}=AR^{-1}$ are similar (also $R^{-\frac{1}{2}}AR^{-\frac{1}{2}}$) if $A$ is symmetric. The Jacobi preconditioner $M^{-1}$ and row-wise $R^{-1}$/column-wise $C^{-1}$ one are equivalent in the case $A$ has the exact same value in each row/column.

Regarding the relationship between Jacobi, the spectral radius, and the condition number I found this:
[Relations between condition numbers and the convergence of the Jacobi method for real positive definite matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256305714_Relations_between_condition_numbers_and_the_convergence_of_the_Jacobi_method_for_real_positive_definite_matrices)

Comment: Many of your questions can be explored experimentally. What experiments have you completed?

Comment: @CarlChristian What experiments do you have in mind? I can only disprove a conjecture using an experiment, I cannot prove any of the statements. E.g. I believe that the preconditioners above do not change the positivity of the eigenvalues, however I have not proven that. I also believe that the eigenvalues for the 3 preconditioned matrices are equal and hence the spectral radii, but I have not proven that either.

Comment: Your first three matrices are similar, hence the eigenvalues are identical. In general,there is no relationship between the spectral radius of a matrix and the condition number for inversion. Explicitly calculating all eigenvalues for some matrices would have suggested the similarity if the three formula did not. Experiments with say triangular matrices could have lead to the second understanding because you can fix the spectra and make the matrices arbitrarily ill-conditioned.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you for pointing that out. Since the three matrices are similar then the condition number of the preconditioned system must be the same. Feel free to formulate your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: In general, the eigenvalues give *no* information about the singular values. You have positive eigenvalues, but you have not assumed that your matrices are symmetric. When you matrix is symmetric positive definite, then the eigenvalues and the singular values are same.

Comment: I am so used to working with symmetric positive definite matrices that I was indeed interchanging singular value for eigenvalue, even though the condition number is defined wrt the singular values.